# How to make ssh forwarding persistent?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh

I've recently needed to forward some ports through an ssh proxy, similarly to this:

```
ssh -L 8700:myurl.mystuff.com:443 user@myproxy.com
```

After doing this a few times for a few ports, I wondered where it was stored.

I looked in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and there's nothing there to show that there's forwarding going on.

I found that I could see the connections using `lsof`:

```
lsof -i -n | egrep 'ssh' lsof
```

but to be honest, I'm not sure why it's showing there.

As is pointed out in the comments, it may not be stored, because it's a running command.  So my question is altered to, how do I make this persistent?

Comment: What makes you believe it's stored anywhere? It's arguments passed to a running command, the state of that command is maintained in the memory area of that process.

Comment: That's an excellent point.  I didn't think of it being non-persistent.  I just assumed it was a setting that would be stored somewhere.  So I guess the question should be changed to, what is the persistent equivalent of this command, and is that stored in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  Thanks, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Forwarding happens over a live ssh session, and sessions are by their nature temporary. You might be able to use something like an @reboot cron job to build a new tunnel every time the computer starts up, but you need to deal with storing authentication, making it recover if the other endpoint reboots, etc...